# Creating m3u8 playlist of all *.ts files in a directory (using batch scripting)

Tags: batch-file, directory, http-live-streaming, playlist

I would like to create a HLS playlist from 300-400 *.ts segments in a directory.

The file names are not continuous numbers (e.g. 0005.ts, 0014.ts, 0024.ts, 0035.ts, etc).

I'm not really familiar with the possibilities of batch files, I could only make the following command: `dir /o:n /b *.ts > playlist.m3u8`, but the result is obviously not a playlist, only a file list.

I need to add extra lines before and in between the file names:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10.000,
0005.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
0014.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
0025.ts
```

I have a feeling it will be a bit more complicated than a 1 line command. Can anyone help?

Comment: So the output file contains a header and then alternating `EXTINF:10.000` constants with .TS files?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do.

Comment: Do you want a one-liner for the command-line? Here it is: `(echo #EXTM3U& echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10& echo #EXT-X-VERSION:3& echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0& (for %a in (*.ts) do @echo #EXTINF:10.000,&echo %a) & echo #EXT-X-ENDLIST) >  playlist.m3u8`

Comment: Thanks @Aacini, your answer solved the problem perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@rem @set prompt=$G

@if "%1" neq "" (@set _outFile=playlist.m3u8) else (@set "_outFile=%1")

@echo #EXTM3U > %_outFile%
@echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10 > %_outFile%
@echo #EXT-X-VERSION:3 > %_outFile%
@echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0 > %_outFile%

@for /f %%G in ('dir /b *.ts') do @call :EmitFileEntries "%%G"
@exit /b 0

:EmitFileEntries
@echo #EXTINF:10.000, > %_outFile%
@echo %%~G > %_outFile%
@exit /b 0
```

Comment: Great. Although it does not create the playlist file for some reason. (I'm using Windows 8.1 if that matters.)

Comment: Just a note, this would create a `m3u` file not a `m3u8` file. I would suggest that the UTF-8 encoding would be a requirement.

Comment: @jwdonahue While this may generate the output mentioned in the question it doesn't necessarily produce a *valid* HLS playlist. The durations must reflect the actual duration of the `.ts` files.

Comment: @aergistal The duration is 10 seconds for all my segments, so that is not a problem. (The parts are created by ffmpeg.)

Comment: @iPog add the `EXT-X-ENDLIST` at the end

Comment: Since the first 128 characters of ASCII are identical to UTF-8, I think we're ok on that score, unless it is run with an odd code page.  I suppose I could force the code page.  I did a little bit of research on the actual format and it seems that a simple list of files would also work as well.  Seems it's not yet a formalized standard.

Comment: Just open it with Notepad++ and change the Encoding.  Or to stay completely with this method, start CMD with the /u parameter, which makes all pipes Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

After working with the above, this is what actually worked for me:

```
@echo #EXTM3U > %1
@echo #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD >> %1
@echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:%2 >> %1
@echo #EXT-X-VERSION:4 >> %1
@echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0 >> %1

@for %%G in (*.ts) do @call :EmitFileEntries "%1" %2 %%G
@echo #EXT-X-ENDLIST >> %1
@exit /b 0

:EmitFileEntries
@echo #EXTINF:%2, >> %1
@echo %3 >> %1
@exit /b 0
```

I require you to pass in the name of the .m3u8 and the segment duration.

Start cmd with the /u parameter.  You can do this from the PowerShell command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mkpl command line utility: https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/mkpl

```
mkpl -d /folder/with/tsfiles -i ts -g UNICODE playlist.m3u8
```